# CSS3 Dropdown menu - Transitions with display none/block?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, transition

I want to create a drop down menu view based on the following HTML / CSS :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        html * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }
        body {
            color: #FFF;
            }
        #panel, #content {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            }
        #panel {
            left: 0;
            width: 750px;
            background: #333;
            z-index: 100;
            padding-top: 200px;
            padding-left: 250px;
            }
        #content {
            background: #000;
            left: 250px;
            right: 0px;
            }
        #panel > nav {
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            }
    .Dropdown {
        position: relative; /* Has to be set, can be overriden */
        }
    .Dropdown > ul {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        }
    .Dropdown:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        }
    .Dropdown > ul, /* On the right by default */
    .Dropdown.Right > ul { /* Deploys on the right side of the label */
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        }
    .Dropdown.Bottom > ul { /* Deploys below the label */
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="panel">

        <nav class="Dropdown Right" style="width: 200px;"><!-- so it can appear on jsfiddle -->
            <div class="Label Parent">Label</div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="Label">Entry</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="Label">Entry</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="Label">Entry</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <nav class="Dropdown Right">
                        <div class="Label Parent">Label</div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class="Label">Entry</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <nav class="Dropdown Right">
                                    <div class="Label Parent">Label</div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="Label">Entry</div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="Label">Entry</div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="Label">Entry</div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <div class="Label">Entry</div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </nav>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="Label">Entry</div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="Label">Entry</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like a developper to be able to extend this drop down CSS to add, for example, a transition between 0 and 1 opacity.
Actually it is not possible with this code because the property display conflicts with the transition one. Adding opacity 0 on the non-hover and opacity 1 on the hover will not work because of that display property.
I've read somewhere on this web site that i could use height 0 and height auto instead of display none and display block (respectivly) but it didn't work either.
Any ideas about how to add transitions please ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your code does not seem to be valid. Why don't you try jsfiddle?

Comment: Well i assume there was a problem while copy pasting it. I did it again, but it's a pain in the ass :(
Anyway, i pasted it on jsfiddle too and it does work.

Comment: Why don't you try to figure out what's wrong with it? It's very simple. =)) Try different browsers, different zoom levels. Start bounty and I will help you to resolve it.

Comment: Copy pasting on stackoverflow seems to create errors when you mix languages like i did, but that code does work. It's ok if you don't want to help ^^